# Как разорвать связь с окном, открытым из кода?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, вкладки, window.open

Открыта страница с адресом `currentUrl.ru`
Открыта вкладка из кода.

Например так:

```
window.open('currentUrl.ru', '_blank');
```

При принте во второй вкладке на первой блокируется выполнение кода. Но если открыть вторую вкладку вручную (нажать плюсик и вбить адрес), то вкладки друг друга не блокируют.

Можно ли разорвать связь между вкладками из кода?

Копипаста функции, которая блокирует все кнопки страницы пока не закрою окно принта:

```
function printThisLayout(layout, styles) {
            if (!styles) styles = '';
            let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
            let onload = 'window.opener = null;' +
                'alert(window.opener);' +
                'window.document.close(); /*necessary for IE >= 10*/' +
                'window.focus(); /*necessary for IE >= 10*/' +
                'window.print();' +
                'window.close();';
            popupWin.document.write(
                '<html>' +
                '<head>' +
                '<style>' + styles + '</style>' +
                '</head>' +
                '<body>' + layout + '</body>' +
                '<script>' + onload + '</script>' +
                '</html>');
        }
```

В открывшемся окне появляется алерт с надписью null, после закрытия алерта открывается диалог принта, а родительская вкладка всё так же висит.

Answer (score 0):

На странице, которая открывается в другой вкладке надо разорвать связь с "родителем"

```
(function() {
    window.opener = null;
})();
```

https://tproger.ru/articles/target-blank-the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

P.S. Добавлено по обсуждению ниже

```
let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
popupWin.onload = function () {
    popupWin.opener = null;
};
```

Comment: Уже пробовал делать window.opener = false; null тоже не сработал)

Comment: Новое окно уже загружено на момент добавления вами контента. Поэтому onLoad в вашем случае похоже не отрабатывает

Comment: Отрабатывает, потому что окно принта открывается

Comment: Надо не в тексте <script></script> добавлять, а сразу. Добавил в ответ

Comment: Я попробовал и так, как вы предложили, и добавить в скрипт. Никак не работает. Даже если на момент выполнения window.print() ссылка на opener порвана, родитель всё равно блокируется. (((((((